# How to subtract 2 months and 18 days from a date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with a date column. I want to subtract 2 months and 18 days from each date in a select.

```
select date from table -- (YYYY-MM-DD)

2014-07-01 
2014-04-21 
2014-08-19
```

I want :

```
select ....

2014-04-13 
2014-02-03 
2014-06-01
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [the `add_months()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions011.htm) to subtract two months, and then simple [date arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#sthref172) to remove a further 18 days:

```
select add_months(<date_field>, -2) - 18
from <your_table>;
```

You can also use intervals:

```
select <date_field> - interval '2' month - interval '18' day
from <your table>;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7fcdd/2).

But the interval approach can get an error if the final or intermediate dates do not exist; if you ran that with an initial date of `2014-04-30` then it would try to take two months off that first, which would give `2014-02-30` - which is not a valid date. [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/119c8/1).

You can also combine them, with `add_months` to subtract two months, and then use an intervals to subtract 18 days.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `add_months` function and `interval` keyword:

```
select add_months(date, -2) - inteval '18' day from table
```

Ref: [Date functions](http://psoug.org/reference/date_func.html)

Comment: @AlexPoole: It seems that you are right. I found it on the Oracle docs server, so I assumed that it was Oracle docs... I corrected the code.